# Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.142 80] only for one IP

Tags: updates, internet-connection

During updates and installations i keep getting errors with connection to [IP: 91.189.88.142 80] and not any others. Does this device has some errors? Can i make so that Ubuntu never tries to use it as it is never working?

Comment: 91.189.88.142 reverses to aerodent.canonical.com (which also forwards back to this IP).  What version of Ubuntu are you running?  What output do you get from **find /etc/apt -type f -exec egrep -i "aerodent|extras" {} +**

Comment: @davidgo i get nothing. I use Ubuntu 20.04 via WSL2

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging and it appears that security.ubuntu.com resolves to this address, among others, and I suspect that this may be your issue.

It is unclear to me why this is throwing up errors for you - it doesn't for me.   A short term fix may be to force your setup to use one of the other security.ubuntu.com addresses -  The "host" command throws up all of the following for it for me:

```
security.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.39
security.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.88.152
security.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.38
security.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.88.142
security.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1360:8001::23
security.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::15
security.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1360:8001::24
security.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1562::18
```

You may be able to hardcode one of the other IPV4 addresses in your /etc/hosts file for security.ubuntu.com.   You could also comment out references to security.ubuntu.com in your /etc/apt/sources.list file.   Apparently commenting this out could cause critical security updates to be delayed though. (Per https://askubuntu.com/questions/185317/are-security-ubuntu-com-updates-eventually-merged-into-normal-updates)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this website does not support HTTPS on port 443
(nor on 80).

This gives an error : https://91.189.88.142/

But this works : http://91.189.88.142/

It gives :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on an Ubuntu 20 behind a corporate firewall.

I am able to download every apt package, except for linux headers.

Changing mirror does not help.

I solved by downloading the .deb with wget (which works) and installing manually.

```
# wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-5.4.0-105_5.4.0-105.119_all.deb
# dpkg -i linux-headers-5.4.0-105_5.4.0-105.119_all.deb
# apt-get install -f
```